# Как избежать переполнения памяти из-за картинок в ListView на Windows Universal app?

Tags: c#, listview, xaml, uwp, windows-phone-8.1

Windows Universal app (Windows 8.1/Windows Phone 8.1).
Имеется ListView лента, в которой иногда могут быть прикреплены картинки к каким-нибудь из записей и чем их больше, тем больше потребление памяти, вплоть до OutOfMemoryException. Как можно реализовать удаление из памяти элементов, которых не видно на экране?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. У ListView стоит по дефолту панель (ItemsStracPanel), которая поддерживает виртуализацию. Microsoft продвигает её, как лучшу на данный момент.
2. Посмотрите на то, как вы устанавливаете картинку. Плохо сказываются случаи, когда вы в Image грузите картинку, которая намного больше отображаемой на экране телефона. Для этого есть хорошое свойство у BitmapImage: `DecodePixelWidth` или `DecodePixelHeight`
3. Чистите старое значение при изменении на новое:

   ```
       var oldImage = image.Source as BitmapImage;
       image.Source = null;
       if (oldImage != null)
       {
           oldImage.UriSource = null;
       }
   ```